# how do i acess my local host wordpress website with friends/

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

I am developing a website using WordPress(XAMP), it's on localhost. I want my friend (on the same network) to be able to access and edit it simultaneously how do I do it?
I want my friend to be able to access this local site from my computer from another computer on the same network using my pc as server for the website

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: Please take a tour of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). have a look at [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) Also on how to [Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should look in settings for your network IP address. Start with that.

Comment: I know you're just starting here, but try to be more detailed and specific when asking questions, so we know exactly what is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to your terminal and type: ipconfig. You can open the terminal pressing the Win key + R.
2. Get your ipv4 address (usually something like 192.168.1.10)
3. Open your notepad **as an administrator**
4. On the notepad, click File > Open and navigate to: "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"
5. On the bottom right corner, you must choose "All Files"
   [image: Notepad Opening All filetypes]
6. Open the file named "hosts"
7. On an empty line, define: **127.0.0.1 yoursitename.localhost**
8. Do steps 1-7 on your friend's computer as well, but instead of 127.0.0.1, define your machine's local IP address you got on *step 2*.
9. Open with any text editor this file: "C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf"
10. Add (but edit) the following to httpd-vhosts.conf

`<VirtualHost *:80> ServerName yoursitename.localhost ServerAlias yoursitename DocumentRoot c:/xampp/htdocs/yourinstalationfolder </VirtualHost>`

11. In some cases you'd have to restart after editing these. Be aware of that
12. Go to http://yoursitename.localhost and install WordPress
13. If you had WordPress previously installed already, you can perform a Search and Replace: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

These are all the default paths for these files, if you have installed Xampp on another folter, be sure to update these paths to your needs.

The extension .localhost is the current recommended by w3c, Google and icann: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761
If you use a registered gTLD here like .com, your browser would try to redirect to an https page and it won't work on your local development. You can see all the benefits on the link above.

Comment: I apologise because I nearly know nothing on the topic and I'm trying to understand a bit, and actually I read on other forums that simply sharing a locally hosted website exposes the computer to a lot of risks (so there are additional softwares that may be used like ngrok)... is this procedure safe instead?